# Conditionally include code for windows mobile

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile

I want to make the code of my application compile differently for windows mobile, since it has fewer features.

To that end, i want to write code like this:

```
#ifndef (_windows_mobile_)
//define avaiabilty of features thatare not supported in windows mobile
#endif
```

What is the macro i should use?

Target plarform is Windows Mobile 6 professional.

I went to http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/, but macro _WIN32_WCE listed there is not defined.

Comment: What kind of development IDE are you using? You could just add  that macro to your build target for windows mobile.

Comment: Visual Studio 2008. I assume there MUST be a macro defined for my platform in SDK, i just cannot find it.

Comment: Is the Windows CE platform SDK set up properly? Because the macro comes from it's headers. Maybe you're just compiling as a desktop target?

Comment: I changed target platform through configuration manager.

Comment: This is a list of [Predefined macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(v=vs.90).aspx) for Visual Studio 2008. I don't see one that relates to mobile development. If there isn't, why not just define one yourself (configure different builds in VS with your own `WINDOWS_MOBILE` macro)?

Comment: Can you lookup the macro in Windows CE platform SDK folder (just do a search in the files for _WIN32_WCE) and see if that include file is used anywhere?

Comment: Rudolfs, you were right. If the project is specifically created for windows mobile with a wiard, there are macros defined, such as UNDER_CE, which are sufficient for my needs.
If you poost an answer, i will accept it.

Comment: Ok, I tried to formulate our discussion in a suitable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should properly define the project and the build target so that the needed macros and headers from Windows CE platform SDK are pulled in, otherwise if building with a bare x86 desktop build target it won't work.

Comment: After i checked, i sound out that macros like UNDER_CE and other, more specific, come from the command line of the compiler in a project properly onfigured for windows mobile development.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a SmartDevice C++ or C# project?

_WIN32_WCE is not a macro but a define you can see in the C/C++ compiler options like /D _WIN32_WCE.

You can also use your own #defines. For example at the top of a C# code and then use #ifdef/#else/'endif in the code file. But using the compile options will make the define visible to all code files.

If your intention is to have the same code files for Win32 (desktop) and WCE you will get problems with the Visual Studio IDE as it does not support this natively like make/cmake and makefiles would do. There have to be different compiler to start etc.

For a C# project there is no different compiler but different assembly to be referenced etc. Possibly you should look for another approach using cross compilers.

You may share some same code files using #ifdef in C#, I already did that for iTextSharpCF.